# using golang logging library, where does one see localhost logs?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-logging

following the [golang library instructions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-go) if you write logs with the client library, where can one see those logs when **running your server locally during development** (eg via `go run main.go`)?

in my case (not sure if it's relevant) i'm using the library as part of golang logic in appengine, and even the [relevant-looking instructions on "viewing logs" for those docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs_using_the_command_line) don't mention local development explicitly. Is that because it (running `gcloud app logs tail` and seeing local server logs) should "just work" or because there's no way to see logs for a local logs sdk interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Tentatively answering myself: that's not supported - instead one has to just conditionally swap out calls to regular logger if env (eg empty `GAE_INSTANCE` env variable) indicates you're on localhost.

Walking through the code under the `NewClient(...)` call on the logging package, I end up a spot where the upstream API is really being called (note the [rpc context used by the very last turtle](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/logging/v1.1.0/logging/apiv2/logging_client.go#L168) - I never saw logic as I walked through that seemed to be switching to something for local development), so I suspect there really is no emulation capturing.

---

EDIT: See [DazWilkin's helpful answer below for more context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63906167/287374)